# Excel 2007 vbe not recognising accented characters

Tags: vba, excel, non-ascii-characters

So I was trying to write a vba code to convert accented characters to regular characters. I had declared all the accented characters as a constant, and the regular characters as another constant. 
But I have trouble inserting certain accented characters into the vba script as the visual basic editor recognise them as '??' only.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅĀÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿěłļņī"
Const RegChars = "SZszYAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuyyellni"
```

So that I can replace AccChars with RegChars.

But when I copy the above lines to vbe, the Const AccChars appears like this:

```
Const AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄ?ĀÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäå?èéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ?????"
```

How can I get vbe accept characters like Ç,ě,ł,ļ,ņ,ī,Å .

I tried changing the font from tools->options and even the Language for non-Unicode programs (System Locale) from control panel. 
I also tried reading the string from another text file, which wasn't effective too.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to type them manually instead of copy paste? Maybe the clipboard from excel '07 is the one guilty

Comment: @Sgdva: Yes..I've tried typing them manually too. It wasn't working.

Comment: You need to use `ChrW()` for unicode characters (that fall out of the range 0-255)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can get the VBE (or a regular messagebox) to **display** characters with a code > 255.  But you can construct a string that will contain those characters by adding the appropriate Unicode characters.  So for your `AccChars` string in your post:

```
Dim AccChars As String
AccChars = "ŠŽšžŸÀÁÂÃÄÅAÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüýÿ" _
        & ChrW(283) & ChrW(322) & ChrW(316) & ChrW(326) & ChrW(299)
```

You can then test for those characters in the strings you are trying to translate.

**EDIT** (additional info):  If you write the string `AccChars` to an Excel cell, or some other object that can display Unicode characters (such as a UserForm.TextBox), you will see the characters appropriately rendered if you select a font that includes Unicode characters.

Comment: Not working man. Its giving blank spaces as outputs for those characters using ChrW()

Comment: @alex_gabriel Since you have provided no code, and since the string AccChars as above does not contain any blank spaces, there is probably an issue with the code that you have not chosen to post.  Does Excel 2007 support Unicode characters?

Comment: @alex_gabriel That code does not contain the string we constructed in this thread. Nor does it allow me to reproduce you getting blank spaces for output.  If you are trying to get the VBA editor to **display** Unicode characters,  I have already posted in my answer that you cannot.  Please read the HELP topics for [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your original post to show this new problem you are having.

Comment: @alex_gabriel If your problem is that you are seeing blanks when you use the code in the previous post, with `AccChars` as shown above substituted for `AccChars` in that UDF, then most likely you neglected to add theappropriate substitution characters to your `RegChars` string.